# Copying files from one folder to another based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table set up on Excel with a list of file paths in column C, and a list of leagues in column G.

What I would like to do is enter a league name into cell H1 and copy all files into a newly created subfolder (if it doesn't already exist) for all the files that match the selected league.

eg in the below, if I had "Essex Olympian Football League Premier Division" in H1, the files for Canning Town, Stortford Swifts, Catholic United, Harold Wood Athletic, Kelvedon Hatch and Leigh Ramblers would copy to a new folder (if it doesn't already exist) located at path & H1 value.

[image]

I have the below code thanks to miss, but it picks up an error if the folder exists with the line `MkDir sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")` - error `run-time error '58': File already exists`

```
Sub Copy_Files()
Dim rng As Range
Dim first found As Long 'we need to hold the row of the first league occurrence
Dim lastRow As Long 'the last row in the G column
Dim sPath As String 'the folder where you need the subfolder created
Dim sFile As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object
'Get a reference of the worksheet. You don't specify which worksheet you are into. I assume this is the first one.
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Clubs")
'This is an easy way to get the last row of data in your worksheet.
    lastRow = ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count + ws.UsedRange.Row - 1
'Specify the folder you need the subfolder to be created into.
    sPath = "W:\Gegenpress Graphics\-- Crests Master\Clubs\Leagues"
'Search if the inserted league exists in column G.
    Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).Find(ws.Range("H1"), , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByColumns, xlNext)
    firstFound = rng.Row
'If the league exists, check if the subfolder exists. If not, create it.
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        If Dir(sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")) = "" Then _
            MkDir sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1")
    'Create the fso object to make the copies.
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
        Do
        'Isolate the file name from the old path.
            sFile = ws.Range("C" & rng.Row)
            sFile = Right(sFile, Len(sFile) - InStrRev(sFile, "\"))
        'Make the copy. True: overwrites the existing file with the same name if any.
            fso.CopyFile Source:=ws.Range("C" & rng.Row), Destination:=sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1") & "\" & sFile, OverWriteFiles:=False
        'Find next league occurence.
            Set rng = ws.Range("G1:G" & lastRow).FindNext(rng)
        Loop Until rng.Row = firstFound 'without this, the find loop never ends
    End If
End Sub
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: Try using `If Dir(sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1"), vbDirectory) Then`...

Comment: I'm getting a type mismatch on that line trying that code?

Comment: `If Dir(sPath & "\" & ws.Range("H1"), vbDirectory) = "" Then`...

Comment: Thank you, but still get  `run-time error '58': File already exists`

Comment: What string do you have in `ws.Range("H1")` when the code raises this error? Move the cursor over this part of the code, when stop on error and it will display the cell value...